# MediaStreamSource is not applying Bitrate Assigned to Media Encoding Profile

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm using media composition to preview videos and to generate streams. I pass a MediaEncoding Profile in which the video container I am assigning the bitrate has to apply when previewing. But it's not working. Here's the code:

```
     MediaEncodingProfile profile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.HD720p);
     profile.Video.Bitrate = 1000000; // Any  Bitrate
     var stream = VideoComposition.GenerateMediaStreamSource(profile);
     videoPlayer.SetMediaStreamSource(stream);
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what the purpose of assigning the bitrate of `MediaEncodingProfile.Video`?

Comment: we are building an app that results in the output video with the user's assigned bitrate to video and audio. 
so to make the user see what's going to change so that the user can select the best as the user wants

Answer (score 0):

By testing, there is no effect in the `MediaStreamSource` when we assign `MediaEncodingProfile.Video.Bitrate` in your scenario.

You could use **Windows.Media.Transcoding** APIs to [transcode video files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/transcode-media-files) from one format to another to show the effect of assigning bitrate.

Please check the following code as a sample:

```
private MediaComposition VideoComposition;
private MediaStreamSource mediaStreamSource;
private StorageFile destination;
……
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
    picker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
    Windows.Storage.StorageFile pickedFile = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    if (pickedFile == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    destination = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("destination.mp4",CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    MediaEncodingProfile profile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.HD720p);

    MediaTranscoder transcoder = new MediaTranscoder();
    profile.Video.Bitrate = 50000; // Any  Bitrate
    PrepareTranscodeResult prepareOp = await
        transcoder.PrepareFileTranscodeAsync(pickedFile, destination, profile);

    if (prepareOp.CanTranscode)
    {
        var transcodeOp = prepareOp.TranscodeAsync();
        transcodeOp.Completed +=
new AsyncActionWithProgressCompletedHandler<double>(TranscodeComplete);
    }
    else
    {
        switch (prepareOp.FailureReason)
        {
            case TranscodeFailureReason.CodecNotFound:
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Codec not found.");
                break;
            case TranscodeFailureReason.InvalidProfile:
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Invalid profile.");
                break;
            default:
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Unknown failure.");
                break;
        }
    }
}

private async void TranscodeComplete(IAsyncActionWithProgress<double> asyncInfo, AsyncStatus asyncStatus)
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () => {
        var stream = await destination.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
        videoPlayer.SetSource(stream, destination.ContentType);
    });
}
```

You could delete the `destination` file if you do not want to save the file.

Comment: but it will take time to provide video since it will transcode first and then I get to play the file for the preview. my sole purpose for this question is to preview the file with user-provided bitrate input we have output already. because it's quite hard to choose the right bitrate, that's why we are thinking about providing a preview but it looks like this might be near to impossible with existing APIs. if you have something then point me in the right direction, it will be helpful I have tried most of the thing i.e. effect, bitrate in encoding profile, etc nothing works
thanks for your help

Comment: We are consulting other engineers, there may be some delays for a reply.

Comment: no worry, we discussed with the team, so now we are providing the app without a preview but we will notify the user by using messages.
thanks for your help.

Comment: You could add a MediaStreamSource.SampleRendered event handler to view the Bitrate value when video is playing.  The [VideoProperties.Bitrate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.core.mediastreamsource.videoproperties?view=winrt-19041#remarks) value for the MSS object shows as the MusicProperties.Bitrate + bitrate value from the encoding profile. And the value of MusicProperties.Bitrate is a consistent 3072000 no matter what the encoding profile defined for audio.

Comment: Though you could set a value of Video.Bitrate for Media Encoding Profile and the setting reflects on the VideoProperties.Bitrate, the result is Bitrate on the Media Encoding Profile is not carried over to the MSS object. There is no way to show the effect of setting Bitrate without transcoding the video. To avoid too much time the transcoding operation cost, you could just select a small clip of video to transcode for users to view.